# Designing a Logo with transparent background

Tags: images, mac, transparency

I want to design a logo which should have a transparent background so that it adjusts automatically with the CSS background color.

I want to do it with pixelmator in mac.

Comment: This really isn't the place for this. Try http://photo.stackexchange.com/ instead, and don't tag with irrelevant stuff (like Photoshop, when you're using Pixelmator).

Comment: Try forming your question in the form of a question. And, no this does not belong on photo.stackexchange.com, it will surely be closed there.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend saving this as PNG24. However, some older versions of Internet Explorer have issues displaying Transparent PNG files. You can get around this using the [BelatedPNG Javascript library](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/).